# How to set the display name for MKPlacemark?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapitem, clplacemark

I'm trying to show routes of two places with Apple's Map.

For the two places, I have both names and coordinates.

```
MKMapItem *currentLocation = [[MKMapItem alloc]
  initWithPlacemark:[[MKPlacemark alloc]
                        initWithCoordinate:paramModel.fromCoordinate2D
                     addressDictionary:nil]];
MKMapItem *toLocation = [[MKMapItem alloc]
  initWithPlacemark:[[MKPlacemark alloc]
                        initWithCoordinate:paramModel.toCoordinate2D
                         addressDictionary:nil]];
return [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[ currentLocation, toLocation ]
                    launchOptions:@{
                      MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey :
                          MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
                    }];
```

The names are stored inside the `paramModel`.

I assume this can be achieved by using `addressDictionary`? I tried  `kABPersonAddressStreetKey` and `kABPersonAddressCityKey`, but neither will show up in the final route view.

Answer (score 0):

Just find out that I can modify the `name` field of `MKMapItem` directly.

```
MKMapItem *currentLocation = [[MKMapItem alloc]
  initWithPlacemark:[[MKPlacemark alloc]
                    initWithCoordinate:paramModel.fromCoordinate2D
                 addressDictionary:nil]];
currentLocation.name = paramModel.fromName;
```

Answer (score -4):

Try creating your MKPlacemark as a variable and then modifying the title field on that variable like so:

```
MKPlacemark* placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                    initWithCoordinate:paramModel.fromCoordinate2D
                 addressDictionary:nil]];
placemark.title = @"Some Title";
placemark.subtitle = @"Some subtitle";
```

Then set the variable as the parameter in your map item constructor.

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems that the `title` and `subtitle` fields are `readonly`?